# Why is the adjusted close equal to the "normal" closing price of the S&P500? (Yahoo finance)

Tags: yahoofinance, sp500

I was looking for both the daily adjusted close and the normal close of the S&P500. On Yahoo Finance i found data that included both of these prices, but the two were identical. These are the R-commands i've used:

```
library(quantmod)
getSymbols("^GSPC",src="yahoo",from="2011-01-01",to="2021-01-01")
```

I also tried it with python, but the same thing happened. The adjusted close and close were equal on every day. Is that a bug? Or is there no difference between the two?

Comment: I would say Yahoo simply does not compute adj. close for indices?

Comment: By the way, yahoo finance also displays an adjusted close (for splits and dividend and/or capital gain distributions) for FX https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/EURUSD%3DX/history?p=EURUSD%3DX